# Get all user activity feeds from the start from Facebook?

Tags: android, ios, facebook, facebook-graph-api, windows-phone-8

I have been searching for past few days but still couldn't get the solution. First we use "Since" parameter to get the solution but I think the Facebook API's got updated and removed this parameter. But even though we can add this parameter in our link but it doesn't work. I tried this using following link.

[https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,feed{message}&since=1349679791](https://graph.facebook.com/me?fields=id,name,feed%7Bmessage%7D&since=1349679791)

Where **1349679791** is the Unix Timestamp format of date **Mon, 08 Oct 2012 07:03:11 GMT**
I also tried by passing date in since parameter from other posts but couldn't get the solution. Please help me out. Or is there any alternate way of doing this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UNTIL** attribute gives you idea about fetching previous post in the Graph API.
First set the limit as 200 in your API call (note that you can retrieve only 200 post per API hit).

For eg.: [`me?fields=id,name,feed.limit(200){message}`](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/145634995501895/?method=GET&path=me%3Ffields%3Did%2Cname&version=v2.1) will fetch you 200 recent feeds. Now use **Next** url in **paging** section to get your remaining 200 feeds (before first 200) and add it to your first 200 post.

Refer to the following image:

[image: example]

Please note again that, you can get only 200 feeds per API hit. Use **NEXT** to get the previous set of 200 feeds ;-).
It works for me. Cheers!

There aren't any specific methods that will fetch the feed from the beginning of the user's joining date.

Hope I make sense.

Answer (score 0):

This API worked fine for me if your aim was to get the the feeds posted by me from a specific date.

https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=id,name,message&until=1349679791

Comment: How could you get? Its not working. Can you post the sample link?

Comment: The link is exactly the same you provided. Just try it in Graph API Explorer. Maybe you missed to add some permissions when you tried in code.

Comment: No, then why should I put bounty on my question? Its not working dude.

Comment: Try the keyword 'until' instead of 'since' and see if that works fine.

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed?fields=id,name,message&until=1349679791     Try this.

Comment: Sorry, its not working actually. It loads some default post by default. Thats it, but not from exact date. That's my problem.